# Solving coupled nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find $z$ such that
$$\dot{z} = -1 + e^{-iz^*},$$
where $*$ denotes complex conjugate and the dots represent derivatives with respect to time. The time dependence of the dependent variables is suppressed for clarity of presentation. Letting $z=x+iy$,
$$\dot{x} = -1 -  e^{-y}\cos x, \quad \dot{y}=  e^{-y}\sin x,$$
together with the constraint that
$$A = -y+ e^{-y}\cos x$$
is a constant, i.e. $\dot{A}=0$.

The normal way I would proceed would be to eliminate $y$ in favor of $x$, which yields product log (ie Lambert W) functions, but the resulting ODE is complicated, and I cannot solve it in closed form. Note, if we take $z = i \log \zeta$, we can equate this to a problem involving a point vortex in a uniform stream, but I'm not sure this identification helps.

Comment: what is $z^*$? $\bar z$?

Comment: What is $\dot{z}$ ? If it is a derivative, with respect to what variable ?

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=-1-e^{-y}\cos(x) \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{-y}\sin(x)
\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^{-y}\sin(x)}{-1-e^{-y}\cos(x)}$$
$$\left(1+e^{-y}\cos(x) \right)dy+e^{-y}\sin(x)dx=0$$
$$dy+d\left(-e^{-y}\cos(x) \right)=0$$
$$y-e^{-y}\cos(x)=\text{constant}$$
This is equivalent to the so called "constrain" :
$$-y+e^{-y}\cos(x)=A$$
Thus this is not realy a constrain. This is the equation of trajectory corresponding to the solution of the original system of ODEs.

The above implicit equation can be explicitly written on various forms :
$$x(y)=\cos^{-1}\left( (y+A)e^y\right)$$
$$y(x)=-A+\text{W}\left(e^A\cos(x) \right)$$
W denotes the Lambert W function.

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{-y}\sin(x)=\pm e^{-y}\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}=\pm e^{-y}\sqrt{1-(y+A)^2e^{2y}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\pm\sqrt{e^{-2y}-(y+A)^2}$$
$$t=\pm\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{e^{-2y}-(y+A)^2}}$$
This gives the analytic solution $t(y)$.

As far as I know, this integral cannot be expressed with a finite number of standard functions. A-fortiori don't expect the inverse function $y(t)$ on explicit form. Better use numerical calculus.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dot{x} = -1 -  e^{-y}\cos x, \quad \dot{y}=  e^{-y}\sin x,$$
$$\sin x \dfrac {dx}{dy}=-e^y- \cos x$$
$$(\cos x)'-\cos x=e^y$$
$$(e^{-y}\cos x)'=1$$
That you can integrate. But the system is not linear so it isn't going to be easy to integrate.